# Grouping on an additional variable in Spotfire

Tags: sql, grouping, spotfire, tibco

I have data on report views per user and respective date of viewing it and would like to calculate the number of new users (i.e. those that accessed a report for a first time in the current month, in this case being Oct 2020) viewing each report.

```
User Report Date Accessed
1     X     01/09/2020
1     X     01/10/2020
1     Y     02/10/2020
2     X     01/10/2020
2     X     02/10/2020
2     Y     03/10/2020
```

Would like to get to this point:

```
Report  New Users
X        1
Y        2
```

Trying with the following code but I realize there is something wrong with the aggregation logic on User. I already have Report as an aggregation column in my cross-table:

`UniqueCount(If(Min[Date Accessed] over [User]>=Date(Year(Today()),Month(today()),1),[User]))`

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> If(Rank(Baserowid(),"asc",[User],[Report])=1,1,0)

As a calculated column in your data.

and create a cross table showing the sum of that column by month.

[image]